# Obtaining ID of inserted row cassandra .Net

Tags: c#, cassandra

I'm using the datastax C# driver to insert a row into a cassandra database, my sample code looks like this:

```
var cluster = Cluster.Builder()
  .AddContactPoints("localhost")
  .Build();

using(cluster)
{
    var connection = cluster.Connect();
    connection.ChangeKeyspace("development");
    var simple = connection.Prepare(@"INSERT INTO test(id,customer,content,created_at,line_ids) VALUES (uuid(), 'test customer', ?,'2014-10-24',?);");

    var cmd = simple.Bind("content",new HashSet<Guid>{ Guid.NewGuid() });


    var result = connection.Execute(cmd);
}
```

How can I obtain the id of the row that I inserted?

Comment: Why not pass in the id yourself? replace uuid() with some guid (created by Guid.NewGuid()) and you'll have it since you were the one who created it in the first place.

Comment: Will that have any performance impact? Are there any requirements on a particular format for a uuid column in Cassandra?

Comment: I don't think it'd have any negative performance impact. The uuid column in Cassandra is a GUID (java's UUID) and is compatible with .Net Guid. Try it with a simple cql insert in command line first and see it works, then you can safely do it in your code :).

Comment: @kha that seems the best solution, could you turn your comment into an answer, so I can accept it, please.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not pass in the id yourself? Replace `uuid()` with some guid (created by `Guid.NewGuid()`) and you'll have it since you were the one who created it in the first place.