# Get the id of the just-inserted row

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, cassandra, cql

My actual problem is that I need to generate unique ids per user. I detail below how I attempted to do it and what problem my solution gave me.

I'm using [cassandra-driver](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver) to insert into this table of my database:

```
CREATE TABLE myspace.unpublished_question (
    user_id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
    account_created timestamp,
    first_name text,
    surname text
)
```

To avoid collisions I thought I would have cassandra auto-generate the uuid's for the primary key column, so I'm inserting like this:

```
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
const cassandraClient = new cassandra.Client({contactPoints: ['localhost'], keyspace: 'myspace'});

const query = 'insert into user (user_id, account_created, first_name, surname) values (uuid(), ?, ?, ?)';
const params = [new Date(), 'John', 'Smith'];
cassandraClient.execute(query, params, {prepare: true}, (err, results) => {
  console.log('Callback arguments:', err, JSON.stringify(results));
});
```

But it only logs this:

```
Callback: null {"info":{"queriedHost":"127.0.0.1:9042","triedHosts":{},"achievedConsistency":10},"columns":null,"pageState":null}
```

There's no way for me to retrieve the `uuid` that cassandra has just generated for this entry.

How can I find out what this uuid was ?

I'd ideally like to be able to do something like:

```
cassandraClient.execute(query, params, {prepare: true}, (err, results) => {
  const uuid = X;
  console.log('User has been given uuid:', uuid);
});
```

Comment: [Does it help ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586686/obtaining-id-of-inserted-row-cassandra-net)

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT that just suggests passing in the uuid myself. Of course this is possible, but how do I ensure that I won't cause a conflict?

Comment: takes a look in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084573/cassandra-generate-a-unique-id). This is a good question you are asking

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT so I change column type to `timeuuid` and then in JavaScript I pass `new Date()`?

Comment: What happens in that case if two inserts are run at exactly the same time

Comment: In the SO post @Richard says `There is a collision probability, but the collision probability (assuming uncorrelated random number sources, which it will be if you generate in Java) is extremely low - if you created 1 billion a second for 100 years the probability of one collision is about 50%. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates for more details.)`

Comment: If it happens you i'll have an error from the database. You can catch it, and call it again (it will generate a new timeuuid) and it's be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The insert operation does not provide the inserted data, so there is no way to obtain it from the server on the same operation.

You will need to generate the `TimeUuid` client side:

```
const id = TimeUuid.now();
client.execute(query, [ id, 'John', 'Smith' ], { prepare: true }, (err, result) => {
  // do something with the id
});
```

See the Node.js documentation on `TimeUuid` for more information: http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/latest/features/datatypes/uuids/#time-uuid